# How to add asset video in nextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am having a `video.mp4` in assets folder in path '../assets/video.mp4'. When I tried to add the video with the following code, it gives the error.

**Code**

```
import video from '../assets/video.mp4';

<video controls>
<source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**Error**

> ./assets/video.mp4 Module parse failed: Unexpected character ''
> (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
> currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this
> binary file)

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but can't you just pass the video source to the element directly? Why import?

Comment: @Phix I am new to nextjs, Your suggestion fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you using nextjs app architecture?

Comment: Yes. Not sure if there is any specific architecture. I have created it with the create-app command